# Publish a website. net 4.0 on a host with. net 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, publish, host, webmatrix

Develop a site on WebMatrix and am trying to publish it.

On the host they hired to support the .net framework 3.5, and the site runs on the .net 4.0.

Is there any way to make it work in 3.5.

In WebMatrix have the option of exchanging .net 4.0 to 2.0 and there's no way to switch to 3.5, with .net 2.0 does not work.

You already paid by the host, then it is not possible to change host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole of the Web Pages (Razor) framework is compiled against .NET 4.0. You cannot get ASP.NET Web Pages sites to run unless .NET 4 is installed on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume switching hosts isn't a possibility?

You can [re-target your project(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) but this may cause issues in the code if you have used features introduced by .net 4.

Comment: I'm using WebMatrix.

Tagets options are. net framework 2.0 and. net framework 4.0
Both (classic, integrated).

I wish my application uses the. net 3.5 (the host accepts up to 3.5)

Comment: Ah, Isee what you mean now.  Bear in mind that .net Framework 3.5 isn't always called "3.5".  It's also known as .Net "2.0.50727".  I'm guessing/hoping that is the value web matrix is offering you as a possible target?  If so, pick that, just another another name for 3.5.